# Turning metric values into buckets in Power bi

Tags: database, powerbi, metrics, bucket, churn

I have two columns of data like this:
[image]

Now I want to turn tenure into buckets like this:
[image]

I've searched but none of those works in Power bi.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very simple way to create groups and buckets. Simply right-click the field you want to group in the right bar and select "New group".

However, I find it quite finicky to use with fixed sized *bins*.

My preferred way it to simply create a new calculated column, using the [`SWITCH` dax function](https://dax.guide/switch/):

```
tenure_group = 
VAR Val = Table[tenure]
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Val <= 5,
    "0-5 months",
    Val > 5 || Val <= 45,
    "6-45 months",
    Val > 45 || <= 69, 
    "46-69 months",
    "70+ months"
)
```

Comment: The syntax for 'Table' is incorrect. (DAX(VAR Val = Table[tenure]RETURNSWITCH( TRUE(), Val <= 5, "0-5 months", Val > 5 || Val <= 45, "6-45 months", Val > 45 || <= 69, "46-69 months", "70+ months"))).

Comment: Yes, *table* is a reserved word. It should be in quotes. I've put it more as a placeholder.
May I suggest to avoid naming a table "Table".

Comment: I changed the code so it's now VAR Val = table1['CCA'[tenure]] and now it gives me this error: The end of the input was reached.

Comment: If your table name is "CCA" and column name is "tenure". Then the syntaxt for the var is `VAR Val = CCA[tenure]`

Comment: I fixed it and now it gives this error: A single value for column 'tenure' in table 'CCA' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max,

Comment: The formula I've provided is for a new **calculated column**. It doesn't work for a measure and would typically return this error.